# Firestore navigation for onUpdate and shuffle an array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this Firebase structure:
[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F43Ap.png).
Then I have a function in my Code, which adds a map called "set".
My Structure is looking like this after: [New structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZKpu.png).

Now i want an onUpdate Firebase function, which is called after the map "set" is added in any document.
This function should shuffle my "question" array.
I tried something like this:

```
 exports.shuffleSet = functions.firestore
    .document('duell/{duell_id}/set/questions')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
  
      const data = change.after.data();
      const previousData = change.before.data();

      if (data.name == previousData.name) {
        return null;
      }
//shuffle code here
    });
```

But Im not sure if `.document('duell/{duell_id}/set/questions')` is the correct way to  navigate to the question array. And at the beginning the "set" is not even existing as explained at the top.

How do I navigate to the question array correctly, that I can pull it & update it shuffled?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a **document path** to `functions.firestore.document()`. You cannot pass a field name, since Firestore Cloud Functions are triggered by documents events.

So you should do as follows:

```
exports.shuffleSet = functions.firestore
  .document('duell/{duell_id}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

  if (!change.after.data().shuffledSet) {

      const data = change.after.data();
      const question = data.set.question;  // get the value of the question field

      const shuffledSet = shuffle(question);  // generate the new, suffled set. It’s up to you to write this function

      return change.after.ref.update({shuffledSet});
   } else {
      return null; // Nothing to do, the shuffled field is already calculated
   }

});
```

Comment: Hello @karste, did you have time to look at the answer? I see in your new question that you now do `exports.shuffleSet = functions.firestore.document('duell/{duell_id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {...});`

Comment: Hey, @Renaud thanks for your answer. I noticed, its easier for me and more comfortable to just set the "set" directly at the creation of the document. Could you please have a look at my new question? Maybe you can find the mistake :)

Comment: @karste "Set the "set" directly at the creation of the document." => this makes sense. If my answer above gave you the solution for your **initial** problem, i.e. "You should pass a document path to `functions.firestore.document()`." (and not a path to a field), please accept it. This way others will know it solves the problem.